# why java stream sum api returns the sum in same data type and not a bigger one?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have some integers which I am adding using Arrays.stream(int arr[]).sum(). It returns the truncated sum in int while the actual sum is bigger and fits in long. why does the stream API returns only int by truncating it but not long?

Tried for small integers like int myArray[] = { 1, 5, 8 };
int sum = Arrays.stream(myArray).sum();

works fine.

but doesn't work for longer integers whose sum leads to long.

Scenario 1 below works fine and returns 14

```
int myArray[] = { 1, 5, 8 };
int sum = Arrays.stream(myArray).sum();
```

while scenario 2 won't work as sum is going beyond 32 bits. it gives sum as -105032716 while expected is 4189934580

```
int myArray[] = { 2094967290, 2094967290};
int sum = Arrays.stream(myArray).sum();
```

and to get the correct sum, if I do below I get the expected result 4189934580

```
long sum = 0L + 2094967290+2094967290;
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: I have not participated in its specification, so I can only guess: probably they didn't want to **always** do a `long` addition (including conversion) even if it clearly is not needed. So the choice is left to the developer, as with simple addition.

Answer (score 6):

This is something that's up to the developer. You know what to expect, what data you're dealing with, and, more importantly, you test it. In my opinion, this is not different from how we handle the possible overflow of any `intOne + intTwo`.

If you know that the sum will exceed the `int` range, then switch to a long stream (thanks to [Carlos Heuberger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812989/why-java-stream-sum-api-returns-the-sum-in-same-data-type-and-not-a-bigger-one/58813063?noredirect=1#comment103904793_58813063) for `asLongStream()` instead of `mapToLong(i -> i)`):

```
long sum = Arrays.stream(myArray).asLongStream().sum();
```

Comment: `asLongStream()` would be *simpler*

Answer (score 4):

You are summing `int`(s) (a 32-bit primitive data type). If you want a `long`, sum `long`(s). This is how primitive math works.

```
int c = 2094967290 + 2094967290;
System.out.println(c);
```

is the same as

```
System.out.println(2094967290 + 2094967290);
```

Using `long`(s)

```
System.out.println(2094967290 + 2094967290L);
```

or with streams like this will yield the correct result here

```
long sum = Arrays.stream(myArray).mapToLong(Long::valueOf).sum();
```

or (as pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58812989/why-java-stream-sum-api-returns-the-sum-in-same-data-type-and-not-a-bigger-one/58813044?noredirect=1#comment103904832_58813044))

```
long sum = Arrays.stream(myArray).asLongStream().sum();
```

However, `long` can also overflow (it is a 64-bit primitive data type). For arbitrary precision, you should use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

```
BigInteger sum = Arrays.stream(myArray).mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
        .reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, (a, b) -> a.add(b));
```

Comment: `asLongStream()` would be *simpler* instead of `mapToLong`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger True enough.